# json can't serialize type with MONGODB and Hibernate-OGM

Tags: json, mongodb, hibernate-ogm

I am trying to run a very simple  query using Hibernate NamedQuery and MongoDB. However when I am trying to add ENUM field into the WHERE condition it throws an exception below. Without enum in WHERE condition works as expected

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: json can't serialize type : class com.entity.model.social.SocialProvider
    at com.mongodb.util.ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.serialize(ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.java:77)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONSerializers$MapSerializer.serialize(JSONSerializers.java:317)
    at com.mongodb.util.ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.serialize(ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONSerializers$IterableSerializer.serialize(JSONSerializers.java:290)
    at com.mongodb.util.ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.serialize(ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONSerializers$MapSerializer.serialize(JSONSerializers.java:317)
    at com.mongodb.util.ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.serialize(ClassMapBasedObjectSerializer.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(JSON.java:55)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(JSON.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:458)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:546)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect$MongoDBResultsCursor.hasNext(MongoDBDialect.java:860)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.query.impl.OgmQueryLoader.listOfEntities(OgmQueryLoader.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.query.impl.OgmQueryLoader.list(OgmQueryLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.query.impl.OgmQueryTranslator.list(OgmQueryTranslator.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
    at com.dao.social.SocialConnectionDao.getConnectionByUserId(SocialConnectionDao.java:37)
    at com.service.social.SocialConnectionServiceImpl.getConnectionByUserId(SocialConnectionServiceImpl.java:39)
    at com.service.social.SocialConnectionServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1d9a6b18.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.service.social.SocialConnectionServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7583977a.getConnectionByUserId(<generated>)
    at test.com.TestSocialConnection.listSocialConnections(TestSocialConnection.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

ENTITY

```
@Entity
@Indexed(index="social_connection")
@NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name = "social.getConnectionUserById", query = "select s from SocialConnection s where s.provider = :provider and s.providerUserId = :providerUserId")
})
@Table(name = "social_connection")
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
public class SocialConnection extends DateEntity {


    private static final transient Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocialConnection.class);

    private SocialProvider provider;

    private String providerUserId;


    public SocialConnection() {
    }


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    public SocialProvider getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(SocialProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @NotNull
    public String getProviderUserId() {
        return providerUserId;
    }

    public void setProviderUserId(String providerUserId) {
        this.providerUserId = providerUserId;
    }
```

ENUM

```
public enum SocialProvider {

    TWITTER("Twitter"),
    FACEBOOK("Facebook"),   
    LINKEDIN("LinkedIn");

    private String name;

    SocialProvider(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

DAO:

```
public SocialConnection getConnectionByUserId(SocialProvider provider, String userId) {     
        TypedQuery<SocialConnection> namedQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("social.getConnectionUserById", SocialConnection.class);   
        namedQuery.setParameter("provider", provider);
        namedQuery.setParameter("providerUserId", userId);
        namedQuery.setMaxResults(1);
        return namedQuery.getSingleResult();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was raised to Hibernate

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-597

Answer (score 0):

In the book "Pro Hibernate and MongoDB", there is an example of ENUM used with entity.
In their code, the enum class is an inner class of the entity.

```
@Entity
@Indexed(index="social_connection")
@NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name = "social.getConnectionUserById", query = "select s from SocialConnection s where s.provider = :provider and s.providerUserId = :providerUserId")})

@Table(name = "social_connection")
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
public class SocialConnection extends DateEntity {

public static enum SocialProvider {

    TWITTER("Twitter"),
    FACEBOOK("Facebook"),   
    LINKEDIN("LinkedIn");

    private String name;

    SocialProvider(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

private static final transient Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocialConnection.class);

private SocialProvider provider;

private String providerUserId;


public SocialConnection() {
}


@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@NotNull
public SocialProvider getProvider() {
    return provider;
}

public void setProvider(SocialProvider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}

@NotNull
public String getProviderUserId() {
    return providerUserId;
}

public void setProviderUserId(String providerUserId) {
    this.providerUserId = providerUserId;
}
```

I did not test it, but maybe it could be a workaround for this bug before it is fixed.